# Trying to add an image inside a CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How would I be able to put an image inside a CSS Grid?

This is all I'm trying to do and can't figure it out.

**This was my attempt at a CSS Grid:**

https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/72/

But it didn’t work as I had expected it would.

The grid isn’t viewable over the image here.

If the grid was viewable the lines would be **Red**.

**Full Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/73/

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/1TbGgqz.png") no-repeat 0 -600px;
}

.wrap svg:hover path {
  fill: #0059dd;
}

.wrap svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap .playa,
.playinga {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap .playb,
.playingb {
  margin: 0 201px 0;
}

.wrap .playc,
.playingc {
  margin: 0 402px 0;
}

.wrap .playd,
.playingd {
  margin: 201px 0 0;
}

.wrap .playe,
.playinge {
  margin: 201px 201px 0;
}

.wrap .playf,
.playingf {
  margin: 201px 402px 0;
}

.wrap .playg,
.playingg {
  margin: 402px 0 0;
}

.wrap .playh,
.playingh {
  margin: 402px 201px 0;
}

.wrap .playi,
.playingi {
  margin: 402px 402px 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="playa" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playinga" data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE"></div>
  </div>
  <svg class="playb" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingb" data-id="-QAnOs-O23c"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playc" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingc" data-id="drNPMrdmqMQ"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playd" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingd" data-id="EBEUhO5_Flk"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playe" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playinge" data-id="wE7khGHVkYY"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playf" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingf" data-id="D5WkP8JZgdw"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playg" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingg" data-id="eI43jkQkrvs"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playh" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingh" data-id="R9C5KMJKluE"></div>
  </div>

  <svg class="playi" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
    <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z"></path>
    <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="hide">
    <div class="video playingi" data-id="J1gE9xvph-A"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what lines ? ...

Comment: Those lines in the image are not part of the grid. It's on the image itself. The lines and border of the Grid are red. My Attempt at doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/72/

Comment: so remove those line from the image then and it's fixed

Comment: No, it's not fixed because I want the red grid lines to appear over the image. Right now they are behind the image. Basically all I’m doing is, adding an image inside a CSS Grid: The lines should be red, I’m doing something wrong, and can’t figure it out. https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/72/

Comment: there is no *grid lines*, it's a background you have defined and this background is covered by the lines in your image. So technically there is no issue since you decided it to make it this way. Remove the lines from the image and it's fine

Comment: here is the image : https://i.imgur.com/1TbGgqz.png where you can clearly see the lines

Comment: How would I make it a different way where the red lines would appear over the image? That's what I'm trying to do. That's what I'm asking for help doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use some gradient in case you cannot change the background image

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border:4px solid red;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) calc(100%/3 - 1px)   0% /4px 100%,
    linear-gradient(red,red) calc(2*100%/3 + 1px) 0% /4px 100%,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0% calc(100%/3 - 1px)   /100% 4px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0% calc(2*100%/3 + 1px) /100% 4px,
    url("https://i.imgur.com/1TbGgqz.png") no-repeat 0 -600px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  
</div>
```